# When doing inference, how to calculate the probability percentage associated with each class?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, inference, softmax

I'm working on a tensorflow MNIST tutorial modification, I have 36 classes.

My NN output:

`[[ -2386.17529297  18497.5546875   12824.89257812  11382.53417969
    5093.64941406  13072.60546875  -4560.9921875   13502.52148438
    6688.22802734 -20945.26953125   9932.95605469  -9839.86816406
  -51489.03515625   5788.45410156 -16452.57421875   6666.68457031
    3585.06298828     56.68802261  12293.05664062  11485.73535156
    8274.83496094  10686.38769531   1002.59674072   7018.57275391
  -10461.40039062  -7438.14501953   4308.97021484 -12628.72949219
  -12593.25390625  17131.04296875 -33693.35546875   8738.546875
    4923.90917969 -19373.60351562  11723.73339844  -2816.69580078]]`

After using softmax:

`[[ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]`

Answer (score 1):

I would say you are getting a one-hot vector due to the large outputs of your model.

The softmax is computed as p_i = exp(o_i) / sum(exp(o_j)).

You are raising e to the power of your outputs, and dividing by the sum of all exponentiations.

Thus, for large values of outputs, your classifier becomes very confident, as you can see e^(18497.55) (your second output) is much greater than all other outputs.

Have you used any regularization in your model? Regularization biases your  model towards smaller weights, and usually ensures smaller outputs.